# TreeContentProvider just getting every Directory of my path. (File Filter)

Tags: java, file, filter, jface, rcp

im trying to get every folder of my path.
Now Im getting just folders but as soon as some other file comes up it gives me a JavaNullPointerException.
I know its beacuse of ***listFiles()*** but I dont know how to let it work otherwise.
Can someone help me?

``

```
@Override
public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) {
    return File.listRoots();
}

@Override
public Object getParent(Object element) {
    return ((File) element).getParentFile();
}

@Override
public boolean hasChildren(Object element) {
    Object[] obj = getChildren(element);       
    return obj == null ? false : obj.length > 0;
    
}

@Override
public Object[] getChildren(Object parentElement) {
    
    List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
        for (File file : ((File) parentElement).listFiles()) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                files.add(file);
            }
        }
    return ((File) parentElement).listFiles();
}
```

Comment: Null pointer where **exactly**?

Comment: Here :
for (File file : ((File) parentElement .listFiles())

Comment: Well listFiles returns null if the File is not a directory causing that error. You must check if it is directory before doing that.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that, do you have an example code for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File.listFiles() returns null if the file is not a directory. This is causing your exception.

To just show directories use something like:

```
@Override
public Object[] getChildren(Object parentElement) {
   File parentFile = (File)parentElement;

   if (!parentFile.isDirectory()) {
      return new Object[0];
   }

   return parentFile.listFiles(File::isDirectory);
}
```